# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un formulario me redireccione a otra pagina dependiendo de el dato ingresado en un campo con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Este es el formulario:

```
<form action="/horassociales/SISTEMAHORAS.html" method="post" id="redirecion">
  <label for="username">Codigo</label>
  <input type="text" name="nombreUsuario" placeholder="Introduzca Codigo" id="Nombre">
  <input type="submit" value="LogIn" id="Send"> 
</form>
```

Y quiero que dependiendo del dato ingresado en el `id="Nombre"` me arroje
si es `DAN003` la acción cambie a `/horassociales/DAN003.html`,
y si es `BDP014`, cambie a `/horassociales/BDP014.html`.

Comment: Buen día, ¿Qué haz intentado hacer?... Pulsa en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/597870/edit) y adjunta tu intento.

Comment: he intentado con este script

Comment: ` <script>
    document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()

      if (document.getElementById('Nombre').value == 'DAN003') 
        document.getElementById(redirecion).setAttribute('action', '/horassociales/Mario.html')
  
      if (document.getElementById('Nombre').value == 'BDP014') 
        document.getElementById(redirecion).setAttribute('action', '/horassociales/Alex.html')
        document.getElementById('redirecion').submit()
      
    })
  </script>`

Comment: pues solo te falta encerrar entre comillas a `redirecion`. También, en la primera línea debería ser `Send` y no `send`.

Comment: gracias de verdad por la ayuda, ya tengo sueño y no me percate en esos pequeños detalles.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Por favor no dejes el código que se te pide en comentarios, debes [edit] tu pregunta y agrega el código a ella, que es a dónde pertenece. Estos comentarios solo son _ruido_ y debieran ser eliminados o, cuando menos, ignorados a la postre.